# Why opencv 'cv2.morphologyEx' operations shift images in one direction during iterations?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently using `"morphologyEx"` operations in OpenCV to eliminate some noise in the image. It's working successfully but for some strange reason, roi keeps moving south during iterations.
The original image is : [image]

The image wth scale bars : [image]

The python script that I am running is

```
test_image = r"C:/test/test.bmp"
image = cv2.imread(test_image,cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2RGB)
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3) 
ret,binary = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_adj = cv2.morphologyEx(blurred, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,(3,11),iterations=25)
#imshow(binary)
imshow(img_adj)
```

But after iterations it is as follows :
[image]

Image roi has shifted south which is proportional to iterations.
How can I prevent shifting ?

Comment: Performing morphology should have zero influence on shifting the image. Is that `imshow` function from matplotlib? Make sure to use `cv2.imshow()` not any other display function. I see some other problems: `iterations=25` you will never ever need this much iterations. After thresholding your image, make sure the desired objects to detect in the foreground are in white and all objects to ignore in the background are black. Create an elliptical shaped kernel with `cv2.getStructuringElement` + `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE` kernel type. Also change kernel size to `(3, 3)` or  `(5, 5)`

Comment: Right now you have a kernel size for removing vertical lines, not for the small circular dots. In fact, I don't think you should use morphology for this since it will also damage the vertical line you're trying to extract. Here's an approach: Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold, find contours, filter using contour threshold area, then any contours that pass this filter are noise so you can effectively remove them by filling them in with  `cv2.drawContours`

Comment: Regardless of the kernel size and the values, the shift is always there even with iterations of 5. But it's lesser. It's proportional to iterations. This seems to be a fundamental issue with this function.

Comment: @PCG it looks like you have managed to confuse everyone... I had to debug your code, because it's not possible that odd kernel size shifts the image. Only after executing the code, I realized that the method accepts structuring element and not size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is the `(3,11)` argument passed to `cv2.morphologyEx`.

According to the documentation of [morphologyEx](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f), kernel is a **Structuring element**, and not the size of the kernel.

Passing `(3,11)` is probably like passing `np.array([1, 1])` (or just undefined behavior).

The correct syntax is passing 3x11 NumPy a array of ones (and `uint8` type):

```
img_adj = cv2.morphologyEx(blurred, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3, 11), np.uint8), iterations=25)
```

---

Using large kernel with 25 iterations is too much, so I reduced it to 3x5 and 5 iterations.

The following code sample shows that the image is not shifted:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

test_image = "test.bmp"
#image = cv2.imread(test_image, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2RGB) # cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2RGB is not in place
image = cv2.imread(test_image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as grayscale
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3) 
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#img_adj = cv2.morphologyEx(blurred, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, (3, 11), iterations=25)
img_adj = cv2.morphologyEx(blurred, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3, 5), np.uint8), iterations=5)

montage_img = np.dstack((255-image, 0*image, 255-img_adj)) # Place image in the blue channel and img_adj in the red channel

# Show original and output images using OpenCV imshow method (instead of using matplotlib)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('img_adj', img_adj)
cv2.imshow('montage_img', montage_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`image`:
[image]

`img_adj`:
[image]

`montage_img`:
[image]

---

A better solution would be finding the largest connected component (that is not the background):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

test_image = "test.bmp"
image = cv2.imread(test_image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as grayscale
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binary, 8)  # Finding connected components

# Find the largest non background component.
# Note: range() starts from 1 since 0 is the background label.
max_label, max_size = max([(i, stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]) for i in range(1, nb_components)], key=lambda x: x[1])

res = np.zeros_like(binary) + 255
res[output == max_label] = 0

cv2.imshow('res', res)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]